# get the text off an item in the ListView

Tags: android, eclipse, listview

I want to remove a item from a list view.. But when i remove the item that i want, the item that is removed is the one that is in the first position.

I have this code..

final String text = (String) lv1.getItemAtPosition(position);
db.removeCategoria(text);

why does not remove the correct position?

Answer (score 0):

You should try

1. clearing up your question a bit, and
2. removing the item from your data
   provider (list / xml /...).

what is `db` anyway?

Comment: db is the class of the database where i have the metode to remove a item by description

Comment: then the problem could be with your `position` member, and/or the return value of the` getItemAtPosition(..)` method. Would you please share what values the position and text variables hold?